# How to iterate through a container in another class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl, tree, iterator

I've come across this issue a few times and would like find out if there is a simple method or pattern I can use to solve it.

Imagine a tree structure where each node contains a STL container (vector) of pointers to children.  I want client code to be able to traverse this tree, and iterate through the child containers to access other parts.

My problem is that I want to maintain encapsulation for my nodes while at the same time letting clients easily see all of the children for that node. I also want to make sure that if a client gets a const reference to the root node in the tree, then all access to subsequent parts of the tree are also const.

Should I try to make an iterator class for my node type, have a node method return vector iterators , or is there a more elegant pattern I'm missing?

**Edit:** I want to stress again that while I see some good ideas presented, I have containers of ***pointers*** to other nodes.  Returning a `vector<node *>::const_iterator` will not prevent clients from calling non-const methods on the node.  It only protects the pointers themselves from pointing at different objects.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this is usually sufficient:

```
class node 
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<node> node_list;
    typedef node_list::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const { return children_.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return children_.end(); }

private:
    node_list children_;
}
```

This allows you to change the underlying container type without changing code that iterates over a `node`'s children.

This does have the disadvantage that it leaks an implementation detail because code that uses your `node::const_iterator` know that it is a random access iterator (because `std::vector:: const_iterator` is a random access iterator), so you might have a hard time switching to a container that didn't support random access.

If you want to be able to control the iterator category yourself, you'll probably want to create your own `iterator` class that provides the exact behavior you want to provide.

Comment: Will this also work if node_list is a vector of pointers to nodes, and I want to the client to only have pointers to const nodes?

Comment: "code knows that it is a random access iterator" interesting point, but equally code also knows that it's specifically a `vector::const_iterator`. However, it's much easier to use `operator+` without thinking, than it is to assign the iterator to `vector<node>::const_iterator` instead of `node::const_iterator` without thinking. I wonder whether there's a case for an iterator adaptor that does nothing other than "downgrade" the iterator it wraps to a specific category. Then you could return `make_forward_iterator(children_.begin())`, or some such.

Comment: @Steve:  Since the category is part of the iterator's type, you'd have to do the conversion in the typedef.  I think you could do that pretty easily though using a `template <RealIteratorT> class forward_iterator_wrapper : private RealIteratorT { };`.  There might be problems; I haven't thought about it in depth.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but rather, an alternative approach.  Rather than have the client code run the show, you could go for [control inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) by registering a callback functor.  For instance:

```
// Derive from this class to create a visitor
class AbstractVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void operator() (const T &) = 0;
};


// Your recursive data-structure class
class MyClass
{
public:
    void walk(AbstractVisitor &v) const
    {
        // Call the client callback
        v(payload);
        for (std::vector<MyClass>::const_iterator it = children.begin();
             it != children.end(); ++it)
        {
            // Recurse
            it->walk(v);
        }
    }

private:
    T payload;   // Some sort of payload associated with the class
    std::vector<MyClass> children;
};


// You could have different visitor classes to do different things
class MyVisitor : public AbstractVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void operator() (const T &t)
    {
        // Do something with t
    }
}


int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    MyVisitor v;
    ...
    m.walk(v);
}
```

Complete encaspulation achieved!

Comment: Visitor pattern! :-O (Well, something related to it, at least.)

Comment: Personally, in C++ I'd want `walk` to be a function template with a functor parameter. Failing that (because sometimes you don't want templates at interface boundaries), I'd want a user data pointer to go with my function pointer, or an interface with a virtual function. Otherwise walk is limited to operations that have no state except global state, and return no value (because it's void). That is, poorly-designed ones ;-)

Comment: @Steve: yes, absolutely; ideally you'd want to be able to provide it with functors.  But that seemed a little complicated to throw together for the code snippet above!

Comment: `std::function<void(T)>` would work, as would a visitor base class with a virtual `operator()` overload.

Comment: @James: Is that a C++0x template?

Comment: @Oli:  `std::function` is an addition in C++0x, yes.  It's currently available in TR1 implementations as `std::tr1::function` and in Boost (as `boost::function`).

Comment: @Oli: While I appreciate the suggestion, and will absolutely consider it in future code, I can't use it in this situation.  I am doing more than performing a recursive walk through the entire tree.

Answer (score 0):

For traversing the entire tree, you would have to create your own iterator class, for just traversing the children, you can safely return the vector iterators.